# GCJ javax.swing.GroupLayout

Tags: java, gcj, grouplayout, libgcj

I am using gnu compiler for java version 4.4.4. It doesn't come with support for javax.swing.GroupLayout. Do later versions come with this support? I have build GCC many times before on my system. Should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupLayout was added to JDK1.6.